# Calculating duration and pricing based on predefined Offers and Time Range

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I've been trying to figure out a way to do this properly but maybe someone could steer me to the right direction as I have spent quite some time trying to do this without success.

I am trying to develop a feature in my application for my gaming centre which allows the user to set different pricing offer based on clock-in/out, here is an example of what I want to achieve :

- Currently I have two pricing offers (will use USD currency as an example) :

  1st Offer range :

  `Offer_Start_Time        Offer_End_Time      ------------------------------------------------ 
      10:00:00 AM               05:00:00 PM`

  2nd Offer range :

  is whatever outside the 1st Offer's range (something like  `05:05:00 PM to 09:59:59 AM`)
- Assuming I have a `Table Tennis` in my club and it has the following settings :

  `1st Offer Pricing is 5 USD
  2nd Offer Pricing is 10 USD`
- So if a customer comes `IN` at `11 AM` and goes `OUT` at `1:15 PM` then application will charge him `5 USD`
- If a customer comes `IN` at `4:40 PM` and goes `OUT` at `09:00 PM` then application should split cost into two ranges as following : 

  `4:40 PM to 05:00 PM will cost him 5 USD 
  5:00 PM to 09:00 PM will cost him 10 USD`

  - Same should work If a customer comes `IN` at `11:40 PM` and goes `OUT` at `02:00 AM (which is the next day)`

What I have done so far which is only working fine when the range is within 1 day :

I first fetch the saved `Offer_Start_Time and Offer_End_Time` from the database then do this

```
 If New TimeSpan(TimeOfDay.Hour, TimeOfDay.Minute, TimeOfDay.Second) >= New TimeSpan(24, 0, 0) And New TimeSpan(TimeOfDay.Hour, TimeOfDay.Minute, TimeOfDay.Second) < New TimeSpan( Offer_End_Time.Hour,  Offer_End_Time.Minute,  Offer_End_Time.Second) Then    
                        Offer_Start_Time= Date.Today.AddDays(-1)
                        Offer_End_Time = Date.Today.AddDays(-1)
                        Offer_Start_Time_NextDay = Date.Today
                    Else
                        Offer_Start_Time= Date.Today
                        Offer_End_Time = Date.Today
                        Offer_Start_Time_NextDay = Date.Today.AddDays(1)
                    End If
```

Then I use below code to get the range and pricing etc..

```
If (INTIME >= Offer_Start_Time And OUTTIME <= Offer_End_Time And OUTTIME < Offer_Start_Time_NextDay) Then
            '  MsgBox("offer 1")

            xTotal_1 = CalculatePrice_Time(Table_Number, INTIME, OUTTIME, PerHour_Price1,PriceType, "Price1")

        ElseIf (INTIME >= Offer_Start_Time And INTIME <= Offer_End_Time And OUTTIME > Offer_End_Time And OUTTIME < Offer_Start_Time_NextDay) Then
            'MsgBox("offer 1+2")

            xTotal_1 = CalculatePrice_Time(Table_Number, INTIME, Offer_End_Time, PerHour_Price1,PriceType, "Price1")

            '+'

            xTotal_2 = CalculatePrice_Time(Table_Number, Offer_End_Time, OUTTIME, PerHour_Price2,PriceType, "Price2")

        ElseIf (INTIME >= Offer_Start_Time And INTIME > Offer_End_Time And OUTTIME > Offer_End_Time And OUTTIME < Offer_Start_Time_NextDay) Then
            ' MsgBox("Offer 2")

            xTotal_2 = CalculatePrice_Time(Table_Number, INTIME, OUTTIME, PerHour_Price2,PriceType, "Price2")
        ElseIf (INTIME >= Offer_Start_Time And OUTTIME > Offer_End_Time And OUTTIME >= Offer_Start_Time_NextDay) Then
            'MsgBox("Offer 2+3")  '3 is the 2nd offer range which is outside 1st offer range

            xTotal_1 = CalculatePrice_Time(Table_Number, INTIME, Offer_Start_Time_NextDay, PerHour_Price1,PriceType, "Price1")

            '+'
            xTotal_2 = CalculatePrice_Time(Table_Number, Offer_Start_Time_NextDay, OUTTIME, PerHour_Price2,PriceType, "Price2")

        End If
```

- `PerHour_Price1` and `PerHour_Price2` values will be fetched from the database where it has the map of `Table Number` and its `Price1` column and `Price2`
- `PriceType` variable holds "C" or "N" where C is the Custom pricing forumla using blocks 0-5,5-10...55-60, and the "N" is the Normal formula where it will multiply total used minutes with the `(PerHour_Price1 or PerHour_Price2)/60`

---

I need help with below :

- I get wrong duration and pricing when assuming customer comes `IN` at `10:00 PM 20/09/2018` and goes `OUT` at `01:00 PM 21/09/2018` keeping in mind that I only have `Time` value in the `Offer_Start_Time` and `Offer_End_Time` range variable
- I want to have the flexibility of adding multiple offers on the same day instead of only two as the current setup. 
  for example :

  `Offer 1 Range 10:00 AM to 01:00 PM 
  Offer 2 Range 01:00 PM to 06:00 PM 
  Offer 3 Range 06:00 PM to 09:59 AM`

I hope my issue is explained clearly

I would be thankful if anyone can help me with this or share the best way to do this as I believe my code is cumbersome and wont work for certain scenarios

---

EDIT (added codes):

```
   Public Function CalculatePrice_Time(ByVal Table_Number As String, ByVal xDateTime_IN As DateTime, ByVal xDateTime_OUT As DateTime _
        , ByVal Price As Double, ByVal PriceType As String, ByVal Price_DBColumn As String) As Double


    Dim Result As Double = 0.0


    Dim Hours_Used As Double = 0
    Dim Minutes_Used As Double = 0

    Dim HourToPrice As Double = 0
    Dim MinutesToPrice As Double = 0


    Dim Usage_Duration As TimeSpan = Calculate_Usage_Time(xDateTime_IN, xDateTime_OUT, True) 'True means return result without rounding to nearest 5 minutes

    Dim Usage_Duration_Rounded As TimeSpan = Calculate_Usage_Time(xDateTime_IN, xDateTime_OUT) 

    Hours_Used = Usage_Duration.Hours

    Minutes_Used = Usage_Duration.Minutes

    If PriceType = "C" Then  'Custom pricing in blocks  0-5,  5-10 ... 55-60
        MinutesToPrice = GetCustomPrice(Table_Number, "C", Minutes_Used, Price_DBColumn)  '<-- this is where I fetch the pricing from database, Price_DBColumn = "Price1" will point to the database column for pricing of Offer 1, and Price2 means Offer 2
    End If

    HourToPrice = Hours_Used * Price

    If PriceType = "C" Then
        Result = HourToPrice + MinutesToPrice
    ElseIf PriceType = "N" Then
        Result = (Price / 60) * Usage_Duration_Rounded.TotalMinutes
    End If

    Return Result

End Function
```

- `GetCustomPrice()` function will search the database which contains data as the example below :

  `Table_Number    Minutes_Start   Minutes_End Price1  Price2
  1                  0                 5      0.050   0.100
  1                  5                10      0.100   0.150
  1                 10                15      0.400   0.500
  .                 ..                ..      .....   .....
  1                 55                60      5.000   10.00`

---

**EDIT :** (showing what I have done with David's sample code)

```
    -Output Test for CalculateOverlapPrice and CalculateOverlapMinutes functions 
for the Range (IN : 23/09/2018 12:00:00 AM , OUT : 23/09/2018 01:00:00 AM)

        [custArrival] : 23/09/2018 12:00:00 AM
        [custExit] : 23/09/2018 01:00:00 AM
        [currentDateOfferStart] : 23/09/2018 10:00:00 AM
        [currentDateOfferEnd] : 23/09/2018 01:00:00 PM
        [offer] : 5  Timing : 10:00 AM - 01:00 PM
        Used Minutes : 0
        Block Price : 0
        -------------------
        [custArrival] : 23/09/2018 12:00:00 AM
        [custExit] : 23/09/2018 01:00:00 AM
        [currentDateOfferStart] : 23/09/2018 01:00:00 PM
        [currentDateOfferEnd] : 23/09/2018 06:00:00 PM
        [offer] : 10  Timing : 01:00 PM - 06:00 PM
        Used Minutes : 0
        Block Price : 0
        -------------------
        [custArrival] : 23/09/2018 12:00:00 AM
        [custExit] : 23/09/2018 01:00:00 AM
        [currentDateOfferStart] : 23/09/2018 06:00:00 PM
        [currentDateOfferEnd] : 24/09/2018 10:00:00 AM
        [offer] : 5  Timing : 06:00 PM - 10:00 AM
        Used Minutes : 0
        Block Price : 0
        -------------------
        Total : 0
        -------------------
```

-Fetching Offer from database and adding them to the list :

```
            Dim Offer_Start As Date = CDate(dRow("TablePrice_StartPeriod"))
            Dim Offer_End As Date = CDate(dRow("TablePrice_EndPeriod"))
            Dim Price As Double = CDbl(dRow("TablePrice_HourlyRate"))

            Offer_Start = New Date(1, 1, 1, Offer_Start.Hour, Offer_Start.Minute, 0)



            If Offer_Start.Hour > Offer_End.Hour Or (Offer_Start.Hour = Offer_End.Hour And Offer_Start.Minute = Offer_End.Minute) Then ' it means offer end next day 

                Offer_End = New Date(1, 1, 2, Offer_End.Hour, Offer_End.Minute, 0)

            Else
                Offer_End = New Date(1, 1, 1, Offer_End.Hour, Offer_End.Minute, 0)

            End If

            Dim T_Offer As New Offer(Offer_Start, Offer_End, Price)


            CurrentOffers.Add(T_Offer)
```

**New**

I have updated my code to fetch offers from database to be compatible with the new split changes David provided and also tweaked it to have them sorted otherwise CurrentOffers(0).StartTime will return the wrong timing which I didn't figure out until I used the sample provided for testing.

```
   Dim DB_Offer_Start As Date = CDate(dRow("TablePrice_StartPeriod"))
   Dim DB_Offer_End As Date = CDate(dRow("TablePrice_EndPeriod"))
   Dim Price As Double = CDbl(dRow("TablePrice_HourlyRate"))

            Dim New_Offer_Start As Date = Nothing
            Dim New_Offer_End As Date = Nothing

            If DB_Offer_Start.Hour > DB_Offer_End.Hour Or (DB_Offer_Start.Hour = DB_Offer_End.Hour And DB_Offer_Start.Minute = DB_Offer_End.Minute) Then ' it means offer end next day 
                '================ Split offer into two ranges  [Before Midnight to midnight    PM to AM]
                New_Offer_Start = New Date(1, 1, 1, DB_Offer_Start.Hour, DB_Offer_Start.Minute, 0)
                New_Offer_End = New Date(1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0)
                CurrentOffers.Add(New Offer(New_Offer_Start, New_Offer_End, Price))
                '======================================
                '================ Split offer into two ranges  [After Midnight to end time  AM to AM/PM]
                New_Offer_Start = New Date(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
                New_Offer_End = New Date(1, 1, 1, DB_Offer_End.Hour, DB_Offer_End.Minute, 0)

                CurrentOffers.Add(New Offer(New_Offer_Start, New_Offer_End, Price))
                '======================================
            Else
                New_Offer_Start = New Date(1, 1, 1, DB_Offer_Start.Hour, DB_Offer_Start.Minute, 0)
                New_Offer_End = New Date(1, 1, 1, DB_Offer_End.Hour, DB_Offer_End.Minute, 0)
                CurrentOffers.Add(New Offer(New_Offer_Start, New_Offer_End, Price))

            End If

        Next

        If CurrentOffers.Count > 0 Then  'Sort to had 0 or 12 AM as first 
            CurrentOffers.Sort(Function(x, y) x.StartTime.CompareTo(y.StartTime))
        End If
```

**Added: Test results**

```
    Offers List 
    [offer] : 5  Timing : 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM - 01/01/0001 10:00:00 AM
    [offer] : 10  Timing : 01/01/0001 10:00:00 AM - 01/01/0001 01:00:00 PM
    [offer] : 5  Timing : 01/01/0001 01:00:00 PM - 01/01/0001 06:00:00 PM
    [offer] : 5  Timing : 01/01/0001 06:00:00 PM - 02/01/0001 12:00:00 AM
=====================================================
    Output for range 22/09/2018 11:00:00 PM - 23/09/2018 11:00:00 AM
    -------------------
    [offer] : 5  Timing : 12:00 AM - 10:00 AM
    Used Minutes : 0
    Block Price : 0
    -------------------
    [offer] : 10  Timing : 10:00 AM - 01:00 PM
    Used Minutes : 0
    Block Price : 0
    -------------------
    [offer] : 5  Timing : 01:00 PM - 06:00 PM
    Used Minutes : 0
    Block Price : 0
    -------------------
    [offer] : 5  Timing : 06:00 PM - 12:00 AM
    Used Minutes : 60
    Block Price : 5
    -------------------
    This is inside the [If custExit.DayOfYear <> custArrival.DayOfYear Then] block
    [offer] : 5  Timing : 12:00 AM - 10:00 AM
    Cust Arrival/Exit Timing : 23/09/2018 12:00:00 AM - 23/09/2018 11:00:00 AM <--- Output of (New Date(custExit.Year, custExit.Month, custExit.Day, 0, 0, 0)) to custExit
    Used Minutes : 600   <---- CalculateOverlapprice ignored the extra 1 hour, because offer block ended at 10 AM? 
    Block Price : 50
    -------------------
    Total : 55
    -------------------
```

Comment: I have working code, but it calculates to exact minutes between arrival and leaving and you are charging by the hour What criteria are you using to decide whether a customer should be charged an extra hour. E.g arriving at 4:40 PM to 05:00 PM will cost him 5 USD, but what if the arrival time is earlier or the departure time is later? Surely the charging should be in blocks of time at the table tennis "table"? with durations of 15/30/60 minutes? If you could edit your question to include the price calculation code so that I can incorporate it into my code. Thanks

Comment: BTW I probably wont be able to get back to this until tomorrow at the soonest because of uncertain work patterns.

Comment: Hi David, I have two types of price charging, the first is per minutes which means that I divide total price by 60 then multiply the result by the minutes used. The other type is in blocks of 5 minutes  (0 - 5 , 5-10, 15-20.... 55-60) and I have assigned the total price breakup to each block for system to fetch from. So if table is used lets say for 1 hour and 5 minutes then system will get the price from 0-5 block and the 55-60 block and add them up. The 55-60 block is always the 1 hour cost.  The reason is that maybe you need to set a certain table to only charge per minutes unlike others.

Comment: David, I have tweaked the previous code and added other codes. Hope that makes it clearer now of what I have and what I am trying to achieve. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After our communications in the comments, I think it may be better is I just give you the function that calculates overlap correctly - Though I suspect that your calculations may work with a tweak to the information in the database.

The sub below is based on the data for each offer being stored in a `Date` object similar to the following class definition

```
Private Class Offer
    Public ReadOnly StartTime As Date
    Public ReadOnly EndTime As Date
    Public ReadOnly Price As Decimal

    Public Sub New(tmpStartTime As Date, tmpEndTime As Date, tmpPrice As Decimal)
        StartTime = tmpStartTime
        EndTime = tmpEndTime
        Price = tmpPrice
    End Sub
End Class
```

You should of course adapt it to your needs if you wish to use it.

Then I created a `List( Of Offer)` and populated it in my test code like this

```
Dim CurrentOffers As New List(Of Offer)
```

**UPDATED**
The offers should look something similar to below, but your offers that cross midnight should be split into two offer ranges for example 1800 to 10am the next day should actually be 12am to 10am and at the end of the days offers you should have an offer running from 6pm to 12am the next day

```
Private Sub TestPopulateCurrentOffers()
    'the dates are 1/1/1 because the date object wont allow a date of 0,0,0
    Dim start1 As Date = New Date(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    Dim end1 As Date = New Date(1, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0)
    Dim start2 As Date = New Date(1, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0)
    Dim end2 As Date = New Date(1, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0)
    Dim start3 As Date = New Date(1, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0)
    Dim end3 As Date = New Date(1, 1, 1, 18, 0, 0)
    Dim start4 As Date = New Date(1, 1, 1, 18, 0, 0)
    Dim end4 As Date = New Date(1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0)
    CurrentOffers.Add(New Offer(start1, end1, 5))
    CurrentOffers.Add(New Offer(start2, end2, 10))
    CurrentOffers.Add(New Offer(start3, end3, 5))
    CurrentOffers.Add(New Offer(start4, end4, 5))
End Sub
```

The following Sub calculates the number of minutes that a customer overlaps an offer. If the arrival time is before, and the departure time is after, then obviously the overlap is for the  total number of minutes in that offer of course.

**Important**
I'm assuming that the information in your database for the offer times is stored as a date format with the year/month/day all being 1. **Apart from the offer ending at midnight which should be 1/1/2 because midnight is the start of the next day.** If not, then you should make sure that when the data is read into your program, that this is the case as I have done above

```
Private Function CalculateOverlapMinutes(daytoCheck As Date, currentoffer As Offer, custArrival As Date, custExit As Date) As Integer
    Dim OverlapMinutes As Integer
    Dim currentDateOfferStart As Date = currentoffer.Start.AddYears(daytoCheck.Year - 1).AddMonths(daytoCheck.Month - 1).AddDays(daytoCheck.Day - 1)
    Dim currentDateOfferEnd As Date = currentoffer.End.AddYears(daytoCheck.Year - 1).AddMonths(daytoCheck.Month - 1).AddDays(daytoCheck.Day - 1)
    If custArrival <= currentDateOfferEnd And custExit >= currentDateOfferStart Then 'calculate which time to use 
        'If customer arrival Is before the offer start time then use the offer start time,
        'because the overlap of the particular offer starts at the offer start time. Otherwise
        'use the customer arrival time because it is after the offer start time
        '
        'if the customer exits after the offer end time, then use the offer end time etc
        Dim overlapStart As Date = If(custArrival < currentDateOfferStart, currentDateOfferStart, custArrival)
        Dim overlapEnd As Date = If(custExit > currentDateOfferEnd, currentDateOfferEnd, custExit)
        'calculate number of minutes of overlap for the offer being checked
        OverlapMinutes = CInt(overlapEnd.Subtract(overlapStart).TotalMinutes)
    Else
        OverlapMinutes = 0
    End If
    Return OverlapMinutes
End Function
```

Finally, this bit of test code simple loops through each offer and compares the amount of overlap and adds each result to the price. This is a simplistic version which you'll need to adapt to your pricing models of course, but you get the idea.

**Updated**

```
Private Function CalculateOverlapPrice(custArrival As Date, custExit As Date) As Decimal
    Dim price As Decimal
    Dim Days As New List(Of Date)
    Dim tmpDate As Date = custArrival.Date
    Do
        Days.Add(tmpDate)
        tmpDate = tmpDate.AddDays(1)
    Loop Until tmpDate > custExit.Date
    For Each checkDay As Date In Days
        For Each [offer] As Offer In CurrentOffers
            price += (CalculateOverlapMinutes(checkDay, [offer], custArrival, custExit) * [offer].Price) / 60
        Next
    Next
    Return price
End Function
```

Hope this all helps

Comment: Hi David, thanks for spending some time sharing this. I will try to incorporate your sample code along with tweaks and will update you on the results. Cheers!

Comment: David, I am happy that I managed to get your sample code working for my case and I had to tweak the database to work with it better, but while testing I found out an issue when trying to fetch from 06:00 PM-10:00 AM offer range in your example. Because we added '2' in the day parameter, I believe the IF statement no longer detects the range properly, not sure if you faced same issue ? I have included the output in my question if you could please look at. I have also included line code used to fetch offers from DB, but I have doubts about the IF statement I used to add '2' in the day parameter.

Comment: I've updated some code. The overnight offers should be split into a midnight to end of offer and a start of offer to midnight. There is also some extra logic in the `CalculateOverlapPrice` to check for end dates that are different to start dates. If so, the amount of time and price for that extra period are also calculated. The extra `If..Then..End If` statement decides if the end date is not the same as the start date and calculates the extra time used in the after midnight offer. It also allows for visiting over midnight at the end of a month and the end of a year.

Comment: Thanks David, the code with offer splitting makes sense now. I will give it a try once I am back from work and will get back to you with updates! Cheers

Comment: Hi again David, I have tested your code and I also added few remarks in the new output after the changes. I believe CurrentOffers should always be sorted by StartTime for the CurrentOffers(0).StartTime to work right? otherwise I was getting weird calculations. I have also noticed (using the new range example I provided) that in the new If block you added, if the end time exceeds the offer end time then it will not calculate the extra time. Not sure if the CalculateOverlapPrice should be tweaks or how the Offers are added to the list? I believe we are getting there but few tweaks are needed.

Comment: Yep. The first offer in the list should be start at 0000 and the last should end at 0000 with a day of 2 instead of one. I'm not sure how things are going wrong, but it seems to work fine for me. I've tested it starting at 0000 and various ending times and also tested at other start times.

Comment: Can you try testing the following range (23/09/2018 10:00:00 AM to 24/09/2018 11:00:00 AM or 12:00:00 PM) and see if you are getting the extra 1 or 2 hours calculated knowing that CurrentOffers(0).EndTime is at 10:00:00 AM . Was trying to figure out how to tweak the calculation function to also use day counts incase (worse case) the table was open for more than 1 or 2 days, maybe then I would get the extra 1 hour after the CurrentOffers(0).EndTime covered. if you get what I mean?

Comment: In reference to my previous comment, how are you managing the calculation in your parking app if customer parks for more than 2 days for instance

Comment: It doesn't. Sorry, I assumed that nobody would play table tennis for that long :-)

Comment: Ill have a look tomorrow - 23:30 here and am falling asleep today :)

Comment: Sorry, I might have not thought of that before as I have used the table tennis as an example. I also have Billiard & Snooker tables where sometimes we conduct events and there was an instance (as a request by our customers) where we kept the tournament on for 2 days something like we started at 5 PM and ended the next day at 2 PM or something. So I am trying to make the calculation work for such unexpected cases. So far your code works perfectly but only that extra bit of tweak is required to cover the extra hours if table is up for more than (n) number of days. Thanks again & good night!

Comment: No worries David, it happens all the time. You can look at it whenever you are free. Thank! :)

Comment: OK - Hopefully this is it! :) A slight re-write of some of the code to allow for checking over several days. Basically a list of days to check is created and the calculation iterates over the all the offers in the list of days instead of a single day and and a bit extra to allow for passing midnight.

Comment: Just for future reference - I'm not complaining at all and i'm smiling as I write this, but it's not a regular thing that people writing answers go to this length to help. Normally questioners are expected to do more figuring out for themselves :-D

Comment: Thanks David, I tested your code and can confirm it works perfectly and my struggle is over now.

Comment: Your second comment made me smile as well as I truly support the fact that people need to figure out solutions themselves but I only turned here seeking assistance from experienced programmers or people who faced same issue after multiple tries until I gave up. And I really appreciate your time and effort you put to help a stranger till the end, it is a rare thing to find nowdays =) . I really dont know how I could thank you for this!

Comment: Kind comments and ticks are all I crave :-D